# What's the best way to upload file from phone to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: android, ios, rest, amazon-s3

We've working on mobile app(Android/IOS) and need to upload a image file to S3.
We confused:

- Can we use oul API rest service that does it

  1. Upload file from mobile to API
  2. API upload file to S3 and save detail in database.
- Directly upload to S3 from Android/ios device and then send sendimage url to API.

  1. From Android/IOS upload file to S3
  2. Send detail to API

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to upload file to S3 from device or from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket ? What is your objective ? Please edit the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Just want to upload file on S3 but need to decide wich one is best way to upload , 1 Direct from android/ios or from API

Answer (score 0):

As stated in AWS [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html):

> Making REST API calls directly from your code can be cumbersome. It requires you to write the necessary code to calculate a valid signature to authenticate your requests.

If it's from learning point of view then you can use REST API so that you under stand the underlying process (unless you don't mind spending additional time for implementation+debugging). But if it's for long-term real work/Project, I would suggest you to use AWS SDK so that you need not spend time in implementing, debugging and maintaining something which is already done. And also the SDK is already converting the HTTP REST API into the application domain/language for you.

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample) for AWS-S3 android example and [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtility-Sample) for IOS example.